# Django: 20 html files: 20 TemplateViews and 20 URL patterns needed?

Tags: django

I have 20 Django simple "foo.html" template files.

Do I need 20 TemplateViews and 20 entries in `url_patterns` or is there a simpler solution?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Using Django 2.1 and class-based views, your `urls.py` should be like this:

```
from django.urls import path

from your_app import views

app_name = 'your_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('foo/<str:name>/', views.Foo.as_view(), name='foo'),
]
```

And your `views.py` like this:

```
from django.views import generic


class Foo(generic.TemplateView):

    def get_template_names(self)
        name = self.kwargs.get('name')
        # compute the template you want, for the example, I just take the name
        template_name = f'your_app/{name}.html'
        return [template_name]
```

And that's all ;)

Comment: This is a really nice solution with CBVs. A small improvement could be to ensure that the template really exists; a static list of allowed template names could be used or some kind of error catching (`except TemplateDoesNotExist:`) could be added somewhere in the view.

Comment: @Ralf It is exactly the purpose of the comment "compute the template you want[...]" so... yeah, definitely ;)

Answer (score 9):

You can have a path like `path('pages/<str:page>, views.pages)`

And then in the view do something similar to:

```
from django.template.loader import get_template
from django.template import TemplateDoesNotExist

def pages(request, page):
    template_name = f'your-app/{page}.html'
    try:
        get_template(template_name)
        return render(request, template_name)
    except TemplateDoesNotExist:
        # returns 404
```

Comment: Is this still the way to go? I thought ClassBasedViews are used today.

Comment: You can do it also with a class based view. But I think don't exist a generic class to do what you want to achieve. You will end up using simple view with a get method and the same body. So, in this case, is indifferent whatever you want to use.

Comment: It does exist: extend `TemplateView`, then set `template_name` accordingly.  However I think you then need to do the logic within `get_context_data()` which you overide.

Comment: @V25 I think the problem with `TemplateView` is that it expects `template_name` to be a str and in this case, it should be evaluated based on the request param. So, at the end it would be more difficult and less clean to do the required modifications to leave working it, than use a simple `View`

Comment: @guettli: There's no reason to prefer a class based view when you can write a function  view that is concise and simple like this. It is possible (but pointless) to rewrite this as a class based view, by subclassing `View` and turning this function into a `get` method.

Comment: @HåkenLid there is a answer provided by User mistiru. It uses CBV and I think it looks good. But I guess this is a personal opinion. Both ways are possible.

Answer (score 0):

## A simpler solution with django 2.x.

Since you sound newer to django, this solution should be much easier. There's no reason to use f strings and try/except blocks with simple things. And I know when I started, class based views made no sense because there was no control flow.

### urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views

app_name = 'article_app'

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.article_list, name='article_list'),
    path('new/', views.article_new, name='article_new'),
    path('<int:art_pk>/', views.article_detail, name='article_detail'),
    path('<int:art_pk>/update/', views.article_update, name='article_update'),
    path('<int:art_pk>/delete/', views.article_delete, name='article_delete'),
    # and so on....
]
```

### views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import Article

def article_detail(request, art_pk):
    article = Article.objects.get(pk=art_pk)
    return render(request, 'articles_app/article_detail.html', {'article': article})
```

### template for article_detail.html

```
{% block maincontent %}

   <div class="article">
     <h2><u>{{ article.title }}</u></h2>
     <h3>By: {{ article.author }} --- Posted / Updated on: {{ article.date }}</h3>
     <p>{{ article.body }}</p>
     <p><a href="{% url 'article_app:article_update' article.pk %}">Update</a> | <a href="{% url 'article_app:article_delete' article.pk %}">Delete</a></p>
     <p><a href="{% url 'article_app:article_list' %}">Back to all articles</a></p>
   </div>

{% endblock maincontent %}
```

---

---

---

## If you had something more complicated:

Lets say it's something that requires a few if/else statements to describe a `Food` model. Example:

#### models.py

```
class Food(models.Model):
    FLAVOR_CHOICES = (
        ('tasty', 'Very yummy'),
        ('disgusting', 'Nasty AF bro!'),
        ('super_sweet', 'For little kids'),
        ('bitter', 'Sure to grow hair on you balls!'),
    )
    food_choice = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=FLAVOR_CHOICES, default='super_sweet')
    # and any other attribute for a Food
```

#### urls.py

```
app_name = 'food_app'

urlpatterns = [
    # ....
    path('<int:food_id>/', views.show_food, name='show_food'),
]
```

#### views.py

```
def show_food(request, food_id):
    food = Food.objects.get(id=food_id)
    if food.food_choice == 'tasty':
        return render(request, 'food_app/food_stats.html', {'tasty': 'Everyone likes tasty things'})
    elif food.food_choice == 'bitter':
        return render(request, 'food_app/food_stats.html', {'bitter': 'Girls do not want to have balls. Sure way to end the gene pool.'})
    # .... and so on with other choices
    else:
        return render(request, 'food_app/food_stats.html')
```

#### Then your food_stats.html template would look something like this

Note that this should be used *instead of creating separate pages for `'bitter.html'`, `'tasty.html'`, `'super_sweet.html'`, etc.*

```
{% block maincontent %}

  <h1>Your choice of food:</h1>

  {% if tasty %}
      <p>{{ tasty.food_choice }}</p>  {# this attribute would show the 2nd value for 'tasty' in the tuple of FLAVOR_CHOICES - 'Very yummy' #}
      <p>{{ tasty }}</p>   {# The value that shows here is the key I set in the view #}

  {% elif disgusting %}
      <p>{{ disgusting.food_choice }}</p>
      <p>{{ disgusting }}</p>

  {% elif super_sweet %}
      <p>{{ super_sweet.food_choice }}</p>
      <p>{{ super_sweet }}</p>

  {% elif bitter %}
      <p>{{ bitter.food_choice }}</p>
      <p>{{ bitter }}</p>

  {% else %}
      <p>No foods bro. You're lame.</p>

  {% endif %}

{% endblock maincontent %}
```

Comment: Your answer starts with "a simpler solution". That's a good start. I see that the answer is very long. For me it is too long.

Comment: I was showing everything that's needed. Since you didn' seem to understand, I thought I'd teach you how it all works together. And if you understood everything but the templates, then just read the templates.

Answer (score 0):

from django.conf.urls import url
from .import views

urlpatterns = [
    # url(r'^/$', views.function_name, name="Page")

```
url(r'^$', views.home, name="Home Page"),
```

]

use this patterns match to show your .html pages